# How can I use JavaScript destructuring assignment when name conflict

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, destructuring

With babel, I can make above work well,

```
import { f as foo } from 'f';
```

and destructuring assignment feature can make above work well too,

```
const { a: { b: { c } } } = { a: { b: { c: 10 } } };
console.log(c);  // => return 10
```

but now I encouter a problem above:

```
const {
  a: { b: { c } },
  a2: { b: { c } }
} = { a: { b: { c: 10 } }, a2: { b: { c: 90 } } };
console.log(c);  // => return 90, but I also want to get c=10.
```

If there is any approaches to make a alias like above work?

```
{
  a: { b: { c as c1 } },
  a2: { b: { c as c2 } }
} = { a: { b: { c: 10 } }, a2: { b: { c: 90 } } };
```

Comment: Import syntax is very different from destructuring syntax, even if their shorthands look superficially similar.

Comment: you can name in the destructuring like normal. `const { a: { b: { c : c1 } } } = {  a: { b: { c: 10 } } };` where `c1` is the resulting variable name, but contains the contents of `a.b.c`

Comment: My question is how to make a alias for same property name, not a invalid property name, but the resolution from the topic you mentioned previously is also work for me, thanks very much!